# Unable to load library : Wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: c

I am executing a C program (compiled with -m32, to check if it can run on 32-bit arch) on RHEL-8 64-bit.

This program is loading a library, which gets generated internally.

I am getting error while loading this library - Wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64.

Please suggest some hints to solve this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to load a 64-bit library in a 32-bit program

Comment: Its a .so file and its getting generated internally, how can I make it suitable for a 32-bit program?

Comment: Compile it with -m32?